# How do i implement shiny selectize inputs that update mutually?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a modularized shiny app. In one module there are 3 different selectize inputs that should update each other in the following manner:

"Upstream"-choices (e.g. inputs in sel_category_1) should change the choice options of "downstream" selectize inputs (i.e. inputs in sel_category_2 and sel_detail).

If only "downstream"-inputs are changed, it should update the selected option of "upstream"-choices but not the choice options.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# base df

df <- tibble::tibble(
  
  cat_1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
  cat_2 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
  cat_detail = c("g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o")
  
)




# define ui_module


test_ui <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidRow(
  
          selectizeInput(
            inputId = ns("sel_category_1"),
            label = "choose cat 1", 
            choices = c(df |> select(cat_1) |> distinct() |> pull() |> str_sort()), 
            selected = "",
            multiple = T,
            options = list(maxItems= 1, 
                           maxOptions= 1500,
                           placeholder= 'put in text or select')
          ),
          
          

          selectizeInput(
            inputId = ns("sel_category_2"),
            label = "choose cat 2", 
            choices = c(df |> select(cat_2) |> distinct() |> pull() |> str_sort()), 
            selected = "",
            multiple = T,
            options = list(maxItems= 1, 
                           maxOptions= 1500,
                           placeholder= 'put in text or select')
          ),
          
          
          selectizeInput(
            inputId = ns("sel_detail"),
            label = "choose detail", 
            choices = c(df |> select(cat_detail) |> distinct() |> pull() |> str_sort()),
            selected = "",
            multiple = T,
            options = list(maxItems= 1, 
                           maxOptions= 1500,
                           placeholder= 'put in text or select')
            
          )
  )
  
  
}



# define server module 

test_server <- function(id) {
  
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    shiny::observeEvent(list(
      input$sel_category_1,
      input$sel_category_2,
      input$sel_detail),
      once = TRUE,
      ignoreInit = TRUE, {
        
        
        
        # function to update selected inputs
        
        
        update_selected <- function(input_category_1,
                                    input_category_2,
                                    input_detail,
                                    coltouse){
          
          tmp_sel <-  df %>%
            {if(!is.null(input_category_1)) dplyr::filter(., cat_1 == input_category_1) else .} %>%
            {if(!is.null(input_category_2)) dplyr::filter(., cat_2 == input_category_2) else .} %>%
            {if(!is.null(input_detail)) dplyr::filter(., cat_detail == input_detail) else .} %>%
            dplyr::select(coltouse) %>%
            dplyr::distinct() %>%
            dplyr::pull()
          
          
          if(base::length(tmp_sel) == 1){base::return(tmp_sel)} else {base::return("")}
          
          
        }
        
        

        
        # update selectize inputs


        updateSelectizeInput(
          inputId = "sel_category_1",
          label = "choose cat 1",
          choices = c(df |> select(cat_1) |> distinct() |> pull() |> str_sort()),
          selected = update_selected(input_category_1 = input$sel_category_1,
                                     input_category_2 = input$sel_category_2,
                                     input_detail = input$sel_detail,
                                     coltouse = "cat_1"),
          server = T,
          options = list(maxItems= 1,
                         maxOptions= 1500,
                         placeholder= 'put in text or select')
        )



        updateSelectizeInput(
          inputId = "sel_category_2",
          label = "choose cat 2",
          choices = c(df %>%
                        {if(!is.null(input$sel_category_1)) dplyr::filter(., cat_1 == input$sel_category_1) else .} %>%
                        select(cat_2) |>
                        distinct() |>
                        pull() |>
                        str_sort()),
          selected = update_selected(input_category_1 = input$sel_category_1,
                                     input_category_2 = input$sel_category_2,
                                     input_detail = input$sel_detail,
                                     coltouse = "cat_2"),
          server = T,
          options = list(maxItems= 1,
                         maxOptions= 1500,
                         placeholder= 'put in text or select')
        )



        updateSelectizeInput(
          inputId = "sel_detail",
          label = "choose detail",
          choices = c(df %>%
                        {if(!is.null(input$sel_category_1)) dplyr::filter(., cat_1 == input$sel_category_1) else .} %>%
                        {if(!is.null(input$sel_category_2)) dplyr::filter(., cat_2 == input$sel_category_2) else .} %>%
                        select(cat_detail) |>
                        distinct() |>
                        pull() |>
                        str_sort()),
          selected = update_selected(input_category_1 = input$sel_category_1,
                                     input_category_2 = input$sel_category_2,
                                     input_detail = input$sel_detail,
                                     coltouse = "cat_detail"),
          server = T,
          options = list(maxItems= 1,
                         maxOptions= 1500,
                         placeholder= 'put in text or select')
        )




      }



    )
    
    
    
  }
  
)
  
}
    







# Define UI with selectize inputs

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  test_ui(id = "test")

    
)

# Define server logic to update selectize inputs
server <- function(input, output) {


  test_server(id = "test")
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

With this code it is not possible to realize the desired behavior. It works in both directions when I run the app for the first time. When i have filled all selectize inputs and want to change the value of e.g. sel_category_2 the other selectize inputs do not update again.

I have tried to include the following into the observeEvent to prevent ending in an infinite loop (and that i dont have to use the once option). But it does not work.

```
  r <- reactiveValues()
        
        observeEvent(input$sel_category_1, {
          
          r$sel_category_1 <- input$sel_category_1
          
        })
        
        observeEvent(input$sel_category_2, {
          
          r$sel_category_2 <- input$sel_category_2
          
        })
        
        observeEvent(input$sel_detail, {
          
          r$sel_detail <- input$sel_category_2
          
        })
```

Another compromise could be to add an action button and reset all values but i want to attain that the user can change the inputs freely and more than one time. Only when the desired combination of inputs is found they should be submitted to a database. It must be ensured that no incorrect combinations of characteristics end up in the database.

Currently the code lacks (at least) a mechanism to get rid of "deprecated" input values and restart the updates.

Is there a solution for this issue?

Comment: You might want to check [selectizeGroupUI](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/selectizeGroup-module.html).

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much.